# Could you build a non-spherical structure that's >1000km long?

Tags: engineering, megastructures

Or would gravity force any object of that size into a sphere?

Comment: Roads can reach that length without gravitational problems. For example the [U.S Route 85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Route_85).

Comment: @Theraot I think the op means 3D structures like a building.

Comment: @NuWin Since when are roads not 3D? Anyway, take the [Great Wall of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China) if it were flat people would just walk over it. Edit 1: won't be much of wall. Edit 2: The OP only ask for one dimension (length). Edit 3: [Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest) not artificial, nor spherical either.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm thinking of something more in line with a cylinder though. An object maybe a few thousand km long and a couple hundred in diameter. Basically a dwarf planet stretched into a snake like play-dough.

Comment: @Z.Schroeder May you include the note about it being a dwarf planet on the question? (And if you choose to, you can remove your comment afterwards; I'll remove this comment once that's done)

Comment: The great wall of china is 21,000km long so obviously yes.

Comment: Do you mean in the vacuum of space?

Comment: @Theraot since he's asking "or will it turn into a sphere" I would assume it is put in space, rather than supported by the curvature of the earth. That road/wall of china essentially is turned into a sphere as its part of the entirety of earth.

Answer (score 19):

Whatever or not an artificial structure in space would be deformed to a sphere due to gravitational forces depends on the material. That tells us the gravitational force and the effort-deformation index.

---

### Known cases

Now, under that idea that we are talking about a..

> [dwarf planet stretched into a snake like play-dough](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55409/could-you-build-a-non-spherical-structure-thats-1000km-long#comment156270_55409)

We can look at the paper [The Potato Radius: a Lower Minimum Size for Dwarf Planets](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1004/1004.1091.pdf) That concludes:

> Our derivation of the ~ 200 km – 300 km potato radius is related to the fact that on Earth, earthquakes away from subduction zones are confined to depths less than ~ 30 km. This is because plastic or ductile deformation of the rocks below 30 km is enough to relieve the deviatoric stress, or pressure differences – the same ductile deformation that allow potatoes, as they increase in mass, to become spheres.

So, 400km in diameter (note that the conclusion is about the radius) is enough for a body in space to become spherical by its own gravity. Again, how much bigger you can build an structure in space avoiding high sphericity depends on the material.

As per [G.H.A. Cole, 2000, Minimum Radius And Mass For A Planetary Body](http://web.archive.org/web/20110606080126/http://www.hull.ac.uk/php/dmsghc/planets/html/v_minimum_radius_and_mass_for_a_planetary_body.htm):

> The lower limit [to maintain spherical form] is met when the mass is so small that the energy of internal gravity per atom has the same magnitude as the energy of the atomic interaction, e<sub>(int)</sub>. Between these mass limits the material comprising the body behaves as a viscous fluid.

The same document gives us the formula:

> R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ [3e<sub>I</sub> / 12.57GdA]<sup>1/2</sup>

Where

- R<sub>(min)</sub> is the minimum radius at which the material would retain sphericity.
- e<sub>I</sub> is the inter-atomic energy (energy of the bonds).
- G is the gravitational constant.
- d is the material density.
- A is the mass per atom of the material.

The document says that:

> For silicates, A ~ 30, d ~ 3x10<sup>3</sup> kg m<sup>-3</sup>, G = 6.67x10<sup>-11</sup> and e<sub>I</sub> ~ 10<sup>-21</sup> J, so that R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ 3x10<sup>5</sup>m. The corresponding mass is M(R<sub>min</sub>) ~ 3.4x10<sup>20</sup> kg. For a largely water-ice composition the radius may be as low as R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ 1.6x10<sup>5</sup> m and the corresponding mass as low as M(R<sub>min</sub>) ~ 10<sup>19</sup> kg. Down to this size the body will maintain a spherical shape. Such mass-radius combinations are fully consistent with those observed for the smallest spherical planetary bodies, namely the small satellites Mimas (of Saturn: R = 195 km, M = 3.8x10<sup>19</sup> kg) and Miranda (of Uranus: R = 235 km, M = 6.89x10<sup>19</sup> kg). The larger asteroids also fit these values.

---

### Made out of Diamond?

Let's take a cylinder of h = 1000 km long and d = 100 km wide (r = 50km).

I'll work in km (kilometers), kg (kilograms) and s (seconds).

We have:

- e<sub>I</sub> = 5.745x10<sup>-25</sup> kg km<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> (C-C bond)
- A = 1.99442×10<sup>-26</sup> kg
- d = 3.515x10<sup>12</sup> kg/km<sup>3</sup>

Taking the formula:

> R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ [3e<sub>I</sub> / 12.57GdA]<sup>1/2</sup>

Rearrange:

> R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ [(3/12.57G) * (e<sub>I</sub>/dA)]<sup>1/2</sup>

Replacing:

> R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ [(3/12.57G) * ((5.745x10<sup>-25</sup> kg km<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>)/((1.99442×10<sup>-26</sup> kg) * 3.515x10<sup>12</sup> kg/km<sup>3</sup>))]<sup>1/2</sup>

[Wolfram|Alphing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B(3%2F12.57G)%20*%20((5.745x10%5E-25%20kg%20km%5E2%2Fs%5E2)%2F((1.99442%C3%9710%5E-26%20kg)%20*%203.515x10%5E12%20kg%2Fkm%5E3))%5D%5E(1%2F2)%20to%20km)

> R<sub>(min)</sub> ~ 5413km

That's how big you can make a structure out of diamond before gravity causes it to behave like an viscous fluid and shape to an sphere.

---

**Calculating deformation (hacky way)**

I'll start by taking the Young Module for diamond: Y = 1210 GPa (on the high end of the spectrum).

The volume of the cylinder is V = π * r<sup>2</sup> * h = π * (50km<sup>2</sup>) * 1000km = 157080 km<sup>3</sup>

The mass of the cylinder is M = V * d = 157080 km<sup>3</sup> * 3.515x10<sup>12</sup> kg/km<sup>3</sup> = 5.521x10<sup>17</sup> kg

We convert the [Young Module to the equivalent Spring Constant](https://notendur.hi.is/eme1/skoli/edl_h05/masteringphysics/11/youngsModulus.htm) and we get k = π * Y / r = k = π * 50km<sup>2</sup> * 1210 GPa / 500km = 3.801x10<sup>14</sup> N/m

---

I'll treat the cylinder to be two halves. So, we have two masses of half of 5.521x10<sup>17</sup> kg, that is 2.761x10<sup>17</sup> kg. And these two masses have their centers 500km apart. So the gravitational force is 2.035x10<sup>13</sup> N

Now we can see how much will each of those masses deform by treating them as a spring: x = 2.035x10<sup>13</sup> N / 3.801x10<sup>14</sup> N/m = 0.05354 m - So the compression is twice that: 0.10708 meters

Meaning that due to gravity the cylinder got compressed by about 10.7 cm (4.21575 inches)

*I belive this is not accurate, and I guess this would be solved integrating the mass, but I don't really know how to build the integral. Hopefully somebody can contribute better calculations.*

Comment: Such a lazy question awarded with such quality answer!

Answer (score 1):

Engineered structures supported by other means than rigid structure can overcome this limitation. One example is a [space fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_fountain) which supports own weight using inertia of fast-moving pellets. Another possibility to counteract gravity is by electric field - have the parts charged so that they repel each other, or magnetic field + superconductor.

Answer (score 1):

[Dwarf planet Haumea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haumea), with dimensions estimated as 1,920 × 1,540 × 990 km, is a real-life example of non-spherical structure larger than 1000 km

[image: Visibly non-spherical Haumea]

While we tend to think about planets as spheres, they are in fact oblate spheroids, due to their rotation. However, it is generally a small enough effect that it can be ignored. Haumea is a special case because, with its light gravity and 4 hours rotation period, it is much more significantly deformed. Interestingly, it didn't cause it to become a flattened sphere as one may expect, but an elongated ellipsoid.

Comment: May not be that surprising. The Earth is an oblate spheroid.

Answer (score 0):

On earth we have structures that stretch for thousands of kilometers without collapsing due to gravity. Some examples include the [Trans-Alaskan Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Alaska_Pipeline_System) (1288km), and the [Great Wall of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China) (21,196km
). In fact the force of gravity is integral to the design of both these structures.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there's Larry Niven's [Ringworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld) which would work fine and wouldn't be susceptible to any torsional stresses of gravitation.

This might be too simple/obvious however.

Comment: Ringworld's built out of the strongest unobtanium known to Man, and for good reason: anything weaker would fly apart under the stresses involved.